# Error 0x8007011B when using AddWindowsPrinterConnection

Tags: vb.net

We have a small app to link printers and it was working before we upgraded to Windows10 - 20h2.  I know we can revert back but we are trying not to because this includes a bunch of security patches.

I hope you guys can help.

```
...more codes here
strSelectedPrinterPath = "\\server\myprinter"

Dim objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
**objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection(strSelectedPrinterPath)**
objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter(strSelectedPrinterPath)
```

Results to:
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException 'Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007011B'

Any insight is highly appreciated.

Thanks...

Comment: Call [AddPrinterConnection()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/addprinterconnection) or [AddPrinterConnection2()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/addprinterconnection2) instead, see whether you get `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` . I'm not sure what `Error 0x8007011B` is, but it could be that is cannot move / copy files to the destination (the Device).

Comment: Find matching cases by googling "windows error 283 add printer". 
 [This one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/562522/event-id-7016-with-error-283-when-deploying-printe.html) is good.

Comment: Googling [0x8007011B](https://www.google.com/search?q=0x8007011B) seems to yield results. A post [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/517533/pint-server-and-print-nightmare-update.html?page=5&pageSize=10&sort=oldest) has a recommendation - see "Tried this and it works (Windows 10)"